# For loop for read.table?

Tags: r, for-loop

I know this is an absolute mess and I apologise. In R I want to add a column to a set of large txt files and then make new txt files with the new columns. I don't get an error message but it takes a long time to run and eventually it gets killed. Is there a better way to run the below or maybe there is a bug still? I'm new to R so still don't know how it normally behaves.

```
files <- dir(".../rsid", pattern= glob2rx("final_rsid_chrom*.txt"))

rsid.db <- list()

for (i in files){
rsid.db[[i]]  <- lapply(i, read.table, header = T, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = F)
rsid.db[[i]]$linkage.new <- apply(rsid_db[[i]], 1, create.alleles.col, "REF", "ALT")
write.table(rsid.db[[i]], "rsid_linkage_new[[i]].txt", quote = FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Roland - I also ran the following separately and it has the same issue (i.e. taking a really long time).

```
 files <- dir("/home/sjk98/rds/rds-jmmh2-projects/iron/novel/novel_iron/cleaned/3_columns_std/rsid", pattern= glob2rx("final_rsid_chrom*.txt"))

 rsid.db <- list()

 rsid.db  <- lapply(files, read.table, header = T, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = F)

 quit()
```

Comment: You need to benchmark/profile your code. There are several steps here that can be time consuming but we can't know what the bottleneck/s are. It could be file reading and writing (use `fread` and `fwrite` from package data.table instead). It could be the `create.alleles.col` function, which appears to be called extremely often (seems likely, nothing we can do easily, maybe use parallelization). It could even be `apply` itself (less likely).

Comment: Also, you need to change the file name when writing to file. As it is, this will create exactly one file and overwrite it in each iteration. Use `sprintf` or something like that to create different file names.

Comment: Thank you Roland. Made some additions above

Comment: Please give us more background, eg. how many files you are reading, how many total MB/GB they consume on disk, how big is your RAM  size...

Comment: Well, try the alternative I suggested. read.table is very slow and there are alternatives that are faster by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some bugs which I think are fixed in the below code. However, if `create.alleles.col` is the time consuming part, we can't help without knowing more about that function.

```
# someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe ".../" is a legit path;
# "../risd" looks for risd in the parent dir of the current working directory.
# I think you want a dot before the * in your regext as the original m* matches
# zero or more m characters
files <- dir("../rsid", pattern = "final_rsid_chrom.*\\.txt", full.names = TRUE)

for (i in files){
  # no need to call lapply on a single item; using a temporary variable
  # instead of a list will release the memory from each file instead of
  # building up in RAM if saved to a list
  rsid.tmp  <- read.table(i, header = TRUE, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  # if create.alleles.col is the time consuming part, we can't help without
  # knowing more about it
  rsid.tmp$linkage.new <- apply(rsid.tmp, 1, create.alleles.col, "REF", "ALT")
  
  # create a new file name with _update appended to the end, i.e., oldname_update.txt
  new_file <- sub("(\\.txt)$", "_updated\\1", i)
  write.table(rsid.tmp, new_file, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I guess `create.alleles.col` is not the (dominant) time critical part (see the second part of the question where the code does not even use this function but is also working quite slow). I suppose "out-of-RAM" issues causing swapping of RAM on disk. It is IMHO generally not the best way to read in all files at once (if they are big) but process them sequentially (releasing the memory after processing each file), eg. re-using `rsid.tmp` instead of `rsid.db[[i]]` within the loop of your code

Comment: @R-Yoda: Oh right, I lost track of that second part. I'll update the answer to process sequentially without saving each file to a list.

Comment: Hello ngwalton and R Yoda,

Yes so .../rsid isn't the real file destination but the files that the script is meant to work on are in rsid folder.

It seems that ngwalton's code works! Thank you so much for that. Unfortunately the the job was killed due to consuming excessive CPU time on the login nodes. So I will have to run it again as a SLURM job. The code did get through Chromosome 1 out of 22. See below:
head -n3 final_rsid_chrom1_updated.txt
CHROM_POS ID REF ALT linkage.new
chr1_100000 rs1331956057 C T C_T
chr1_100000002 rs1462733795 C T C_T
chr1_100000004 rs373074226 G A A_G

Comment: @SpencerK: As @Roland suggested, you might consider using data.table and/or processing your files in parallel. It can be a pain to get your environment setup on the cluser, but changing the above code to use `foreach` should give you a big decrease in processing time if you have many files. You might want to run the analysis for a single file on SLURM to see how long it takes. Then you can decide if you want  to wait that long x n files or if you want to invest in getting parallel working.

Comment: @SpencerK: Also, if you're submitting your job to SLURM anyway, you could setup your job submission to loop over your files names and start a new job for each file. That way you could have a single R file that takes a file name as an input argument. This is a way of processing your files at the same time without using parallel in R. Not which will be more work on your setup.